# Field History Not Updating

Tags: custom-field

I am tracking a custom Date field on the Account object because some of my records have mysteriously been updating. I've noticed that the field history takes note of my deleting of the value, but doesn't seem to audit the field getting set (which is what I am interested in). I've looked through the org and haven't been able to locate any custom code or workflow field updates that would update the field, so my question is whether there are any other ways a field could get updated and not audited.

**UPDATE:** It has happened again, and here is some intrigue to add. All of the accounts in the system were touched for an update this morning, and a new account has had the date switched from blank to a date. No activity history or chatter history update. Last modified date was from the "touch". Strangest part -- there is a validation rule on this field that says you can't give it a value unless a picklist is set to a certain value..and it is not.

Comment: Since its a custom field i would suggest if a chatter is enabled track the change through chatter.You can notice who is updating and whats missing or some workflow or custom code is causing this

Comment: Is this any different that enabling Track History on a field?

Comment: Ya its little different.Do you have chatter enabled you can track the field then

Comment: It would seem like the handiwork of a workflow or some code. You could have a user exclusion flag in the validation rule which lets certain users through?

Comment: As stupid as it sounds - check the "Setup Audit Trail" if anybody has disabled the field tracking & val. rule, performed his changes, enabled them back?

Comment: Double checked these. Validation rule is active and not modified in a few months. I don't think there are any exclusions purposely built into this specific system, so I'm trying to determine what sort of updating mechanism would have the power to bypass validation.

Comment: I would file a support case. The only time I've heard of any issues is if there was custom apex code that may handle the update in a strange fashion but you've already identified that this is not the case. If you file a case, then support can work with you troubleshoot this issue.

Answer (score 3):

If field history tracking is turned on then the value changes would be recorded no matter what the channel of the change. I've turned field history tracking on and seen values changing via everything from workflows to the web service Api being audited.

Worth checking if the LastModifiedDate and LastModifiedBy are throwing up an clues on who/ what's modifying the data. Do you have integrations writing to salesforce via the Api?

Lastly, just to double check that field history tracking was indeed enabled when the alleged changes took place.

Comment: Good idea. Unfortunately in this case the field has been readjusted to remove the rogue data, but I'll notify the users to make note of this next time.

Answer (score 2):

If someone sets the value during record creation, it won't be recorded in the history tracking. It only tracks changes after the record has been created.

Comment: Interestingly, these records are multiple years old and haven't been touched in a while until the update.